# Stop a Jquery function on a specific window size

Tags: jquery, function, window, size

I have a function on Jquery, that when the user scrolls down, the  animates becoming smaller. But I want that function to stop working when the window size is lower than 1024px...

I mean, when the the window size is lower than 1024px, the  wont animate, it will stay the same size always. So this function will work only if the window size is bigger than 1024px.

Here is the code...

```
$(function(){
    $('header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 30) 
    {
        if($('header').data('size') == 'big')
        {
            $('header').data('size','small');
            $('header').stop().animate({"height":"60px"}, 200, 'easeOutQuad');
            $('nav ul').stop().animate({"padding-top":"0", "margin":"0.84em 0"}, 200);
            $('#logo').stop().animate({"padding-top":"0.5em", "padding-bottom":"0.6em"}, 200);
            $('#logo img').stop().animate({"width":"170px", "height":"40px"}, 200);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('header').data('size') == 'small')
        {
            $('header').data('size','big');
            $('header').stop().animate({"height":"92px"}, 200, 'easeOutQuad');
            $('nav ul').stop().animate({"padding-top":"0.68em", "padding-bottom":"0.77em", "margin":"1em 0"}, 200);
            $('#logo').stop().animate({"padding-top":"1em", "padding-bottom":"1.35em"}, 200);
            $('#logo img').stop().animate({"width":"215px", "height":"50px"}, 200);
        }  
    }
});
```

How can I make that happen?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) or [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) functions. Something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    // Check window height or width
    if ($(window).height() <= 1024) return;

    ...
```

As an aside, you may want to [debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) your logic, since this function may be called quite a lot while the user is scrolling (which may affect performance).